# Magento 2 add a different container per store

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, store-view

At the moment I have the following code in a layout xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>Contact Us</title>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
      <container name="map" as="map" before="page.top" label="Map" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="map">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="map" template="Magento_Contact::map.phtml" />
      </container>
</referenceContainer>
</body>
```

My question is how do I change the block based on the store view

Comment: I would use a separate theme for the view and therefore layout xml can be set for each view. Just base it on the other theme and change what is needed.

Comment: This is literally the only item I need to change so a new theme seems overkill. Is there no other way?

Comment: Ive never tried it but <STORE_default> where default is the store code may work? I have added an answer but its a bit of a guess based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787089/is-it-possible-to-define-magento-layout-updates-on-a-per-store-basis

Comment: hmm yeah i tried replacing the page node with default / STORE_code and it didnt throw an error but dont think it worked.. not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below: Where `default` is for the default store view and `STORE_store2` is the handle for Store 2 with `store2` as the store view **code**:

```
<default>
  <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
      <container name="map" as="map" before="page.top" label="Map" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="map">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="map" template="Magento_Contact::map.phtml" />
      </container>
  </referenceContainer>
</default>
<STORE_store2>
  <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper.custom">
      <container name="map" as="map" before="page.top" label="Map" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="map">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="map" template="Magento_Contact::map.phtml" />
      </container>
  </referenceContainer>
</STORE_store2>
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but unfortunately I get Element 'default': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( attribute, block, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, container, move, uiComponent ).

Comment: Yeah woulda been lucky. What is the whole xml?

Comment: I have updated the question to have the whole xml

Comment: So what is the answer for this please? Do the `<STORE_code>` stanza's go around the root `<page>` node, the inner `<body>` node or the reference stanza's?? Thanks!